# How to determine if user doesn't contain a role

Tags: c#, discord

I'm working on some new commands in my Discord BOT and I am trying to determine the difference between a user who has an Admin role and a user who has a Founder & Admin Role.

If the user roles contains only Admin and not Founder then they are classed as "CheckUserIsAdminOnly". I use the below code to currently check if the user of the command is an Admin so I've now tried to adapt this to say if the user has an "Admin" role but doesn't contain a "Founder" role.

I feel I am missing something simple here but I cannot figure out my mistake

```
return (fullContextUser.Roles.Where(x => 
x.Name == "Admin" || 
x.Name == "Head Recruiter" && 
x.Name != "Founder").Count() > 0);
```

This code still returns back as true when a user has a role called "Admin" and "Founder"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, this also didn't work, it still returns as true and classes as an Admin even though i have Founder role

Comment: Just a hint, use Any instead of Where + Count > 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Roles` is a list of roles. You cannot make a statement about the list by only looking at individual roles and their names as you do.

The expression in the `Where` will be applied to each individual role in the list.

Check for the existence of the roles and then combine that information.

```
bool hasAdminRole = fullContextUser.Roles.Any(x => x.Name == "Admin");
bool hasFounderRole = fullContextUser.Roles.Any(x => x.Name == "Founder");

bool isAdminButNotFounder = hasAdminRole && !hasFounderRole;
```

Comment: Thank you!, this makes total sense now you've pointed it out. means i can fix something else that wasn't working too!

Answer (score -1):

You are missing paranthesis:

```
return (fullContextUser.Roles.Where(x => 
(x.Name == "Admin" || 
x.Name == "Head Recruiter") && 
x.Name != "Founder").Count() > 0);
```

Comment: By the what is the purpose of this? `x.Name == "Head Recruiter"`. Method would also returns true if user is a Head Recruiter.

Comment: That's not the problem here. As soon as `Roles` contains the role `Admin` the count will be larger than 0, no matter what - because a single role can't be `Admin` and `Founder` at the same time. See @NineBerry answer.

Comment: It would only be more than 0 when user is not founder also. Thats the purpose of and operator here.

Comment: No, it does not work like this because you are only look at an individual role entry at a time.

Comment: Of Course it would. Assume he as the two roles `Admin` and `Founder`. On the first go it checks `("Admin" == "Admin" || "Admin" == "Head Recruiter") && "Admin" != "Founder")`. The result will be `(True || False) && True`. Which is `True`. The check for `Founder` will return `False`. So there is at least one role for which the check is `True`. This is also explained in the answer of NineBerry.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. I was taking an individual row of the role, not all roles associated with this user.